# How to split Rails App for user interface and API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to split Rails App for user interface and API. We are planning to build the API interfaces using `rails --api` and would like to separate the user interface using Rails views in a separate code base. Since we might migrate the user interface to React JS later. Are there any guidelines for separation of backend + user interface code.

I don't want the user interface + API code to co-exist since we would like to scale the API part separately

Answer (score 2):

I would:

- create new set of API controllers for that, something like UserApiController
- create new routes, someting like /api/v1.0/users/list;
- keep controllers as thin as possible;
- reuse services as much as possible;
- create separate module for to/from json/xml convertings

Answer (score -1):

The actual technical solution is pretty simple.

You can just setup two completely separate rails applications - an API app and a frontend application. You can generate the apps with:

```
rails new app my_app_api --api
rails new app my_app
```

Each lives in its own repository and can be developed separately. Each app runs on its own server/dynos/whatever. You can mount them on the same domain (example.com and api.example.com) by tweaking your domain CNAME settings.

You can share code between the apps such as models by creating a [rails engine](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html) (a gem that can be mounted in rails). The gem does [not need to be public](https://depfu.com/blog/2017/08/02/bundler-and-private-dependencies).

The advantages to this approach is that you can use a leaner server for your API as it does not need the middleware/gems needed for anything else than spitting out JSON and that development of the API can be decoupled. The disadvantage is the increased complexity and potential duplication of code and effort.

However what you really should consider is that the effort in setting up the separate frontend rails application is pretty much wasted if the desired end goal is a SPA. It may not be any faster to create a rails frontend and you won't actually be able to reuse much in the way of code. You will also be duplicating most of the server side logic such as routes and controllers.

The development of your API can also be hampered if you are not "eating your own dogfood".

Comment: I'm not saying the approach is wrong - there are plenty of large scale applications with a rails frontend and an api. But it may not be the ideal solution if you are creating a greenfield product.